# Classic ASP result set - ultimate confusion!

Tags: asp-classic

Consider a simple result set from a mysql query.

```
rs("description")
```

and

```
rs("description").Value
```

should be considered as the same thing.  However, depending on how you access them, you get different results (!!)

Access rs("description") directly and you are returned a "Field" object.  Or, more importantly, use it directly in a call, and you are returned a "Field" object.

```
mydescription = rs("description") + " is the description"
```

Assign it to another variable, and the Value of that object is assigned...

```
mydescription = rs("description")
```

the contents of "mydescription" is a string.

Why this difference?  At one point in the life of ASP they must have both worked exactly the same, so why have they changed, and how can I change it back?

Comment: If this is vbScript, the `Set` statement meant setting an object, otherwise it would pass the value. Maybe that have changed?

Comment: Try using the proper operator: `mydescription = rs("description") & " is the description"` this way ASP should treat both as strings thus perform the automatic conversion..

Comment: My question is really...why has this stopped working?  It's code that works on a server...regardless of how bad it is.  I just don't understand

Comment: `+` operator is used between numbers, so ASP is trying to convert `rs("description")` to number and when it fails (or see in advance it's not numeric) it reverts to its true type which is indeed Field object. Using the `&` operator ASP should try converting the value to string and succeed.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to manage recordsets is using arrays.  This will give a huge (huge) performance improvement.  I've found sometimes recordsets can be ambiguous as well as you described, unreliable and slow.  Doing this should resolve all your issues:

```
rsCommon.open "SELECT ID, name FROM tblPeople", adoCon
    arrData = rsCommon.getRows()
rsCommon.close

for i = 0 to ubound(arrData,2)

    response.write(arrData[0][i] & " - " & arrData[1][i] & "<br />")

next
```

Comment: Totally agree - if I had the time I'd go through the whole code base and change it, alas I don't at the moment.  It's on the list, but at the moment it just needs to work as it is

Answer (score 2):

You actually doing two different things in:

### Case 1

`mydescription = rs("description") + " is the description"`

and,

### Case 2

`mydescription = rs("description")`

In **Case 2**, you are accessing the object in the record set.  In **Case 1** you are accessing the object in the recordset, converting the object to a string and concatenating it with another string with the value `"is the description"`.  This is not easy to determine, because in ASP Classic the cast is implicit.  Basically **Case 1** is the same as `mydescription = CStr(rs("description")) + "is the description"`.   If you look at it that way its easy to see why you are not getting the expected result.

Comment: I get the same issues regardless of how I use rs("description").  It "used" to work (probably on IIS6), and now it doesn't.

Comment: @Paul perhaps you should look for the value in the db field description. as it works in one environment and not in another the only difference could be the data. and as asp does this implicit conversion thing the data is quite important

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has never changed, as far as I'm aware.

rs("description") has always returned the ADO Field object.

It just so happens that (conveniently) the default property of the field object is the '.value' property, which for most situations, works just fine.

If you always want to be sure that you're accessing the actual data of the recordset field, then you will always specify the ".value" property. It's the best way to be sure you don't end up with a Field object somewhere you don't want it. If you omit the .value property, then you're leaving it in the hands of vbscript and ADO to make the decision for you.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms678086.aspx